# Auditing n to m relationships in Audit.NET (DB-first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, audit.net

I'm adding [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET)/EF to a legacy DB-first project.  (It uses an edmx file built from the database schema to generate the domain model.)

The DB has a many-to-many relationship between table A and table B modeled as usual with a linking table A_B.  The domain model generated however doesn't have an A_B class.  Instead, A has a container of Bs, and B has a container of As.

I'm finding that changes to the associations between A and B are not being seen by Audit.NET.  (It does see the changes to A fields or B fields).

Am I missing something?  Or is this simply not possible in Audit.NET?

Ref: [GitHub Audit.NET issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [issue #78](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/78)

You need to set the [`IncludeIndependantAssociations`](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#settings) setting to true, to include the independant associations (many-to-many relations without a join entity):

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
    .ForAnyContext(cfg => cfg
        .IncludeIndependantAssociations());
```

Note they are logged in a different property of the event output on [`EntityFrameworkEvent.Associations`](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#output-details)

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.AddOnCreatedAction(scope =>
{
    var associations = scope.GetEntityFrameworkEvent().Associations;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That solved my problem.  Thanks for the very clear answer!